# Dynamic Binding

Tags: java

I would like to know the advantage of `Dynamic Binding` in java.

```
public class Animal {
    public String type = "mammal";

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("The animal is a: " + type);
    }
}
public class Dog extends Animal {  
    public String type;   

    public Dog(String type){  
        this.type = type;  
    }  

    public void show() {  
        System.out.println("The dog is a: " + type);  
    }  
}  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Animal doggie = new Dog("daschund");
        doggie.show(); // "The dog is a: daschund"  (dynamic binding)
        System.out.println("The type is: " + doggie.type); //"The type is: mammal" (static binding)
    }
```

I think, it is a Inheritance strategies. But some people call like Dynamic Binding. That's why, I assume what will be strange in it.

Comment: The advantage compared to what?

Comment: @Keppil: Compared to "static binding". (See the last comment in the OP's the source-code.) Inherited instance methods are overridden, so a call to `doggie.show()` calls `Dog.show`, which prints `Dog.type` -- "dynamic binding" -- whereas fields are never overridden, so a use of `doggie.type` uses `Animal.type` -- "static binding".

Comment: @ruakh: Ah, the `static binding` part wasn't visible, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *benefit* of it is that your behaviour is bound to the type of the object that you invoke it on, without you knowing what precise type it actually is. e.g. if you're passed an Animal, you don't know whether it's a Cat/Dog/whatever, but it'll adopt the appropriate behaviour regardless.

e.g.

```
public void makeNoise(List<Animal> animals) {
   for (Animal a : animals) {
      a.makeNoise();
   }
}
```

The above will bark, miaow, bleet etc. appropriately for each animal in the above collection.

I can pass you something and providing it adheres to the required Animal interface, your code will continue to work if/when I introduce a new animal at a later stage. Your code doesn't need to know the mechanics of how a `Dog` barks - just that you instruct that behaviour through the appropriate method.

Note: I think your example above would be clearer by making `Animal` an abstract class. That way your behaviour will largely come from the derived concrete classes.

Comment: I think, it is a `Inheritance` strategies. But some people call like `Dynamic Binding`. That's why, I assume what will be strange in it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Static binding in Java occurs during Compile time while Dynamic
   binding occurs during Runtime.
2. private, final and static methods and variables uses static
   binding and bonded by compiler while virtual methods are bonded
   during runtime based upon runtime object.
3. Static binding uses Type(Class in Java)  information for binding
   while Dynamic binding uses Object to resolve binding.
4. Overloaded methods are bonded using static binding while
   overridden methods are bonded during compile time.

Answer (score 0):

You gave a simple example of inheritance and polymorphism. Class `Dog` extends `Animal` overriding its method `show()`. It means that the concrete implementation of `show()` being called is determined at run-time and depends on concrete type of animal.

This allows programmer to create logic that does not depend on concrete implementation using it via interface. In your case `Dog` and `Cat` can provide different implementation of `show()` but it caller can use `show()` without knowing concrete type of animal.